# Cut out one SVG <path> out of another one

Tags: image, vector, svg

I have several SVG paths looking like this:

```
M204.21121687607624,196.94037184487675L329.92080751248244,195.46306542867487A130,130,0,0,0,244.46261863233696,77.83995929783192Z
M198.39145828733604,195.04941765207442L235.83285625620988,75.03597952801854A130,130,0,0,0,97.55860203112616,119.9640082076644Z
```

I now want to add another path, but, instead of adding it to the shape, cut it out from the previous paths. How can I accomplish this?

I couldn't find any information on this in the SVG docs - thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cut one shape inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-inside-another)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To expand on [Tobias Snoad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575057/1366033), picking up the pen with the **Move** command and drawing a second shape *in the opposite direction* (as [Brian Hempel pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560835/cut-out-one-svg-path-out-of-another-one#comment53137682_14575057)), will remove that section from the original path.  This is due to the [`fill-rule:evenodd`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/painting/fillrule-evenodd.svg) (default) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7716523/1366033).

Here's an example that will draw a 10x10 box and then reverse a 6x6 box inside it:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://wwww3org/2000/svg" height="200" viewBox="0,0,10,10">
  <path d="M 0,0 h 10 v 10 h -10 z
           M 2,2 v  6 h  6 v  -6 z" /> 
</svg>
```

Which will produce the second box in the image below, with each point numbered and arrowed so you can see direction:

[image: Path Orientation]

#### Here's a running demo is Stack Snippets

```css
svg path.shape {
  fill: green;
  stroke: #1b1b1b;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
svg path.arrow {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: .1px;
}
svg text {
  font-size: .8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-width: .1px;
  text-anchor: middle;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
}
svg circle {
  r: .5;
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-width: .1px;
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://wwww3org/2000/svg" height="200" viewBox="-2,-2,14,14">

  <defs>
    <marker id='arrow' orient="auto"  
          refX='-.9' refY='1'
          markerWidth='2' markerHeight='2' >
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M 0,0 V 2 L 1,1 Z' class="arrow"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>    

  <path d="M 0,0 h 10 v 10 h -10 z
           M 2,2 h  6 v  6 h  -6 z"  
        marker-mid='url(#arrow)' class="shape" />
                             
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" />                  
    <text    x="0"  y="0" > 1</text>    
    <circle cx="10" cy="0" />                  
    <text    x="10"  y="0" > 2</text>  
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" />                  
    <text    x="10"  y="10" > 3</text>  
    <circle cx="0" cy="10" />                  
    <text    x="0"  y="10" > 4</text>  
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" />                  
    <text    x="2"  y="2" > 5</text>  
    <circle cx="8" cy="2" />                  
    <text    x="8"  y="2" > 6</text>  
    <circle cx="8" cy="8" />                  
    <text    x="8"  y="8" > 7</text>  
    <circle cx="2" cy="8" />                  
    <text    x="2"  y="8" > 8</text>  
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://wwww3org/2000/svg" height="200" viewBox="-2,-2,14,14">
 
  <path d="M 0,0 h 10 v 10 h -10 z
           M 2,2 v  6 h  6 v  -6 z" 
        marker-mid='url(#arrow)' class="shape" /> 
   
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" />                  
    <text    x="0"  y="0" > 1</text>    
    <circle cx="10" cy="0" />                  
    <text    x="10"  y="0" > 2</text>  
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" />                  
    <text    x="10"  y="10" > 3</text>  
    <circle cx="0" cy="10" />                  
    <text    x="0"  y="10" > 4</text>  
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" />                  
    <text    x="2"  y="2" > 5</text>  
    <circle cx="2" cy="8" />                  
    <text    x="2"  y="8" > 6</text>      
    <circle cx="8" cy="8" />                  
    <text    x="8"  y="8" > 7</text>  
    <circle cx="8" cy="2" />                  
    <text    x="8"  y="2" > 8</text>  
</svg>
```

#### SVG Path Command Refresher

**Two Variations**:

- `M 100,150` Uppercase (**Absolute**) - Move to *exact coordinates* `100,150` (*x,y*)
- `m 100,150` Lowercase (**Relative**) - Move the pen `100` down and `150` right of where you are

**Straight Commands**:

- `M x,y` - Pick the pen up and **M**ove it to the point *`x,y`*
- `L x,y` - Draw a straight **L**ine to the point *`x,y`*
- `H x` - Draw a line **H**orizontally to the right by *`x`*
- `V y` - Draw a line **V**ertically down by *`y`*
- `Z|z` - Closes the path by drawing a straight line back to the start (last M location)
  **NOTE**: `Z` is *completely optional* - it's just a shortcut to get back to the starting point

**Curved Commands**:

- `C cX1,cY1 cX2,cY2 eX,eY` - Draw a Bezier **C**urve based on *Two* bezier controls point and end at the coordinates *`eX,eY`*
- `S cX2,cY2 eX,eY` - Draw a **S**implifed Curve based on the previous `S|C` control point and *One* specified bezier control point and end at the coordinates *`eX,eY`*
- `Q cX2,cY2 eX,eY` - Draw a **Q**uadratic Curve based on *One* bezier control point and end at the coordinates *`eX,eY`*
- `T eX,eY` - Draw a **T**erminal Quadratic Curve based on the previous bezier control point and end at the coordinates *`eX,eY`*
- `A rX,rY rotation, arc, sweep, eX,eY` - Draw an Elliptical **A**rc for an oval with the specified width *`rX`* and height *`rY`*.  Define the *`rotation`* with degrees and direction with 0|1 for *`arc`* and *`sweep`* and end at the coordinates *`eX,eY`*

> **TIP**: In most instances you can simplify the precision of any automatically generated path points without sacrificing any human discernibility, even when scaled heavily. You can do a regex [find **`([0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*)`** and replace with **`$1`**](https://regexr.com/3iu1s) to remove any trailing decimals.  You can also format each command on it's own line with [find **`\s*([a-zA-z])\s*`** and replace with **`\n$1`**](https://regexr.com/3n9g0) .

#### Further Reading:

- [MDN - SVG Tutorial Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)
- [The SVG `path` Syntax: An Illustrated Guide](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/)
- [How to place arrow head triangles on SVG lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11808860/1366033)
- [How To Create SVG Arrowheads and Polymarkers](https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-markers/)
- [SVG center text in circle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28128491/1366033)

Comment: [The default value is `nonzero`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty). If the `file-rule` is `evenodd`, then you can draw in any direction to achieve the hole.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a single path:

```
M 0,0 l 0,10 10,0 0,-10 -10,0 z m 2,2 l 6,0 0,6 -6,0 0,-6 z
```

This will draw a 10x10 square with an 6x6 hole cut out of the middle

Comment: Just make sure to get the clockwise/counterclockwise ordering of the cutout correct. If your cut-out isn't cut out, reverse the ordering of the points.

Comment: @BrianHempel, unless the `fill-rule` property is `evenodd`.

Answer (score 1):

SVG does not support boolean operations on paths. You can, however, use one path as a [clipping path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath), which will give you the effect you want.

Comment: `Clip-Path` will only allow you to bound a shape within another, defining a non-rectangular container.  But I don't believe you can cut out the middle with clip-path, doing so would act like a container for the whole shape and you'd *only get the middle.  You can possibly add a [`mask`](https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/), but there are some limitations there as well.

Answer (score -1):

Vector graphics editors usually provide this for you. In Inkscape select the two paths and then what operation you want to perform on the "Path" menu. Illustrator has the same functionality too.