# SVG overwrite with transparency

Tags: svg, transparency

I have this svg:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="100" r="50"  stroke-width="0" fill="orange"/>
<polygon points="0,100, 50,50 100,100" fill="white"/>
```

The background is transparent. The polygon overwrites the circle with white color, but I want this area to be transparent (instead of white). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fill-rule: evenodd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty) property with `path`:s to "cut holes" to your shapes:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path fill="orange"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      d="M50 50 L100 100 L0 100
         A50 50 0 0 1 100 100
         A50 50 0 0 1 0 100 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-from-another