# Converting an svg with fill-rule="evenodd" to fill-rule="nonzero"

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I have an svg with a single path with fill-rule="even-odd". I have to convert it into a font and doing so would require me to use an svg without fill-rule="even-odd". So I was wondering if theres a way to get rid of that programatically.

Here is my svg `(https://pastebin.com/raw/bcKncqUZ)`

Thanks

Comment: Just search for the string `fill-rule="evenodd"` and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you need to change **path directions** for inner "cut-out"-shapes.
For less complex svgs you could use javascript to do this programatically as described in this related question ["auto colour fill when Generate Font from svg figma icon using icomoon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379177/auto-colour-fill-when-generate-font-from-svg-figma-icon-using-icomoon/72451714#72451714)

In your case - you need to do this manually.
Use a vector editor like inkscape (or Adobe Illustrator).

First you need to **remove unnecessary elements** like the image caption.
The caption would be way too tiny in a glyph/character.

Open your svg in inkscape.
Run these Path operations:

[image: inkscape: Break apart]

1. select all
2. Path / Break apart
3. Path / Exclusion
4. save the svg

[image: inkscape: remove overlap]

[image: inkscape: Path / Exclusion]