# How to create a transparent logo on a black background

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG that has a black background and a transparent logo path (cut out of the black rect)

Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27 27">
    <!-- Background (black) -->
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/> 

    <!-- Logo (should be transparent/cut out) -->
    <path fill="white" d="M 3.7 2.8 L 19.5 2.9 C 21.6 7.5 24.179 10.775 23.794 11.738 C 21.4 15.9 18.2 20.6 15.9 24.2 L 3.3 24.1 L 3.3 23.8 c 5.768 -0.15 8.852 0.351 10.047 -0.305 C 18.7 14.3 20.7 13.1 20.2 11.9 L 15.3 3.2 L 3.7 3.1 z"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: So essentially you want the path to be a cut out in the rectangle, right?

Comment: Probable duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-inside-another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cut one shape inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-inside-another)

Comment: Why are people so quick to close questions without guiding new contributors?  
To me this is someone looking for <mask>.    

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27 27">
 <mask id="logo-mask">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" />
  <path fill="black" d="M 3.7 2.8 L 19.5 2.9 C 21.6 7.5 24.179 10.775 23.794 11.738 C 21.4 15.9 18.2 20.6 15.9 24.2 L 3.3 24.1 L 3.3 23.8 c 5.768 -0.15 8.852 0.351 10.047 -0.305 C 18.7 14.3 20.7 13.1 20.2 11.9 L 15.3 3.2 L 3.7 3.1 z"/>
 </mask>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#logo-mask)" />
 </svg>

Comment: @JakobE Thank You so much, been trying to do this for the past hour.

Comment: @JakobE I would say because it's clear they made absolutely no attempt at doing the research needed to solve their own problem.